# Logout member on browser close

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms-authentication, membership-provider

How can I configure my membership provider to not use persistent cookies (i.e. to ensure that the member is logged out when the browser is close)?

Answer (score 2):

That's the default behavior of the membership provider (no persistent cookie is created). Pass true as second argument to the [SetAuthCookie](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twk5762b.aspx) method if you want persistent cookies to be used.

Comment: The membership provider I'm using is the Umbraco one.  It seems to be using persistent cookies regardless of what is being set.

Comment: @user81951, and you expect us knowing those things, the fact that you are using Umbarco one? Why didn't you tell all this information in your question? Why didn't you show the code you are using to login in your question? Why didn't you provide a link to the documentation of the control you are using as it is not a standard one?